# Will heating diatomic oxygen enough break the O=O bonds?

Tags: bond, kinetics, enthalpy

The bond enthalpy associated with a $\ce{O=O}$ double bond is equal to 495 kJ/mol. Does that mean that adding enough kinetic energy in the form of heat will eventually cause the bonds to break and create monoatomic oxygen?

Comment: Yes. Adding enough thermal energy to anything will disrupt the bonds.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, adding at least 495 kJ/mol of kinetic energy one way or another (thermally, photochemically by irradiation with photons of that energy, sonication, etc.) will cause $\ce{O2}$ to dissociate into monatomic oxygen.

$$\ce{O2 ->C[energy]\ 2O}$$

Answer (score 6):

Yes. For quantitative information see [Gas Phase Reaction Kinetics of Neutral Oxygen Species](http://www.nist.gov/data/nsrds/NSRDS-NBS-20.pdf), particularly section 2.1, especially table 4, which gives the equillibrium constant $K_D$ as a function of temperature.

where

$K_D = \frac{[O]^2}{[O_2]}$

$K_D$ exceeds 1 above ~1000K, in units of particles per cubic centimeter.

Answer (score 4):

It is important to point out that heat is a bulk (statistical mechanical) concept while bond strength is largely quantum mechanical.  If I am not mistaken, heat/temperature can be defined using pictures like molecules striking the edges of a container, or perhaps from energy/entropy relationships that involve Avagadro's number of molecules.

To your question, this means that given a large enough thermal energy, other molecules of $\ce{O2}$ will likely collide with an $\ce{O_2}$ molecule in question -- thereby bringing their nuclear kinetic energy to bear, and perhaps causing a dissociation.

I don't think that an isolated molecule of $\ce{O_2}$ (or anything for that matter) will spontaneously rupture because of heat, because here heat is not a well-defined quantum mechanical concept, as it is mediated by many moving atoms.

Answer (score 1):

In principle yes, but it will need much more than 495 kJ/mol for sure.

The bond enthalpy is based on (experimental) enthalpy of formation. It does not take into account the enthalpy reaction barrier of the $\ce{O2}$ dissociation.

Comment: Ah, interesting! I knew it would need more but not _much more_ Approximately how much more would you say?

Comment: "much more than 495 kJ/mol for sure"  Hmmm, remember that the molecules have a Boltzmann distribution of energies to begin with.

Comment: Did you mean Boltzmann's kT contribution? At room temperature it will be less than 1 kcal/mol, very insignificant to the enthalpy barrier.

Comment: I mean there is a large distribution of kinetic energy in the molecules in the sample, such that even at room temperature some will occasionally dissociate.

Comment: By enthalpy reaction barrier, do you mean an activation energy? There is no activation energy whatsoever for bond formation; atoms at infinity have zero potential energy, and at any value below that up to a certain equilibrium distance (the bond distance), it's a downhill slope. The curve can be modeled coarsely by [a Lennard-Jones potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential). Thus, the inverse processes of bond breaking only requires 495 kJ/mol to separate the atoms infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

It sure will. But as soon as the gas cools down it will just re-form into O<sub>2</sub> unless you give it something else to react with.

It's possible to get it to react with fluorine at around 700 degrees by heating O<sub>2</sub> and F<sub>2</sub> through it. You now have monatomic O and F ready to party, the fluorine in particular "[losing it's gentle and forgiving nature](http://pipeline.corante.com/archives/2010/02/23/things_i_wont_work_with_dioxygen_difluoride.php)" when reduced to single life. After cooling (to 90K), you will have a flask full of FOOF. That's assuming you still have an intact lab (hint: please do not ever try this, for your sake or the sake of others in your vicinity *--Ed.*).

Comment: Thank you for your username homage, but it was not appreciated.  Continued misbehavior will result in suspension.

Answer (score 0):

Heating it even further will rip all the electrons away from the nuclei themselves to create a plasma state of free floating positive nuclei and electrons whereby, if enough energy was put into the system, the oxygen nuclei would fuse http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen-burning_process